# Integer matrices which are not a power

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrix-equations, arithmetic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$In a group $G$, an element $g$ is said to be primitive if there is no $h \in G$ and integer $n >1$ such that $g = h^n$. (For clarification, I consider finite order elements to be not primitive)

I was wondering, in the case $G$ is $\SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ or $\Sp_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$, if there exists a criterion for primitivity of matrices. I actually even struggle to find examples of primitives matrices in these groups.

In $\Sp_{2}(\mathbb{Z})=\SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}$ is primitive. (This can be shown by considering its action on $\mathbb{H^2}$, for example.)

But this does not generalize (easily at least) to higher dimension. For example, and quite surprisingly maybe
$$
\pmatrix {1 & 0 & 0& 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\  0 & 1& -1 & 0 }^3 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 0& 0 & 1}
$$

Anyway, it seems like some things should be known, but it is very hard to find anything on google since primitive matrix usually means something else ….
I would appreciate any input.

Comment: The MO post "Condition for a matrix to be a perfect power of an integer matrix" seems relevant, although it doesn't have a complete answer to your question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375584/condition-for-a-matrix-to-be-a-perfect-power-of-an-integer-matrix

Comment: There is lots of literature on surjectivity of word maps including, in particular, surjectivity of power maps, for various groups. Your question is harder because power maps are clearly not surjective on SL(n,Z) but, still, this might be something worth searching.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson wait, if $a^2=1$ then $a=a^3$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Some group theorists say that generators of a maximal finite cyclic subgroup are primitive. Some do not. Anyway, it's up to OP to decide whether finite order elements count.

Comment: @DenisT I follow his definition in the first paragraph of the post.

Comment: The problem in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ or $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is easily solvable using the amalgam decomposition. For $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$, $d\ge 3$ I don't even see in an obvious way that it's algorithmically solvable, but I'm pretty sure it is; how efficiently, I'm less sure.

Comment: About primitive: it can be shown that every element of infinite order in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ (or in any of its subgroups) of infinite order is a power of a primitive element: indeed every abelian subgroup in such a group is finitely generated (use that it's a discrete subgroup of its Zariski closure, which is a virtually connected abelian Lie group).

Comment: @YCor: that argument seems to specialize to a slightly weaker version of Dirichlet’s unit theorem, right (minus the exact count of the number of generators)? Neato.

Comment: By contrast, every unipotent matrix in ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is a power of a unipotent matrix in ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ (for a unipotent matrix in ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ is conjugate to all of its (non-identity) powers).

Answer (score 26):

> I actually even struggle to find examples of primitives matrices in these groups.

Here is a relatively easy sufficient condition. If $M \in SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is the $k^{th}$ power of some other matrix $N$ then every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $N$ has the property that $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, and conversely. If we can choose $M$ and an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $M$ such that every $k^{th}$ root of $\mu$ has the property that its minimal polynomial has degree larger than $n$, then $N$ cannot exist.

For this to work $\mu$ can't be a root of unity. As an explicit example we'll take $M = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right]$, the Fibonacci matrix augmented by a $-1$ to live in $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$, whose eigenvalues are $-1$ and the golden ratios $\phi, \varphi = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Any $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^k = \phi, \varphi$ for $k \ge 2$ generates an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and hence is either equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ or else has even degree greater than $2$ and so at least $4$. Moreover $\lambda$ is an algebraic integer and a unit.

But $\phi, \varphi$ each generate the unit group of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})} = \mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ (up to signs). So if $\mathbb{Q}(\lambda) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ then $\lambda$ must be $\pm \phi$ or $\pm \varphi$, but this is ruled out by taking the absolute value. So the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ must have degree at least $4$, which means $\lambda$ can't be an eigenvalue of a matrix in $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$.